# Code-Server Certbot Error during Challenge

Tags: nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt, certbot, code-server

I am trying to install HTTPS using certbot on AWS ec2 instances that running code-server app but got this error:

IMPORTANT NOTES:

- The following errors were reported by the server:

  Domain: code.bamdev.id
  Type:   unauthorized
  Detail: Invalid response from
  http://code.bamdev.id/.well-known/acme-challenge/Tm_vAByOeXE8TuUiX8Ug_EYMlfeCXXe0Eohop2IJnRo

It surely nothing to do with DNS records because the app is working well on HTTP. I already tried the step by step guide here https://github.com/cdr/code-server/blob/v3.8.0/doc/guide.md. Am I missing something?